# How to tap text on a Screen and select word

Tags: jquery, mobile, tablet

I have been searching google for the best approach on how to allow a user to tap a word within a paragraph, on a phone or tablet, and the word they tapped on brings an action.

For best performance on any device, and the text being dynamic, whats the best approach using Jquery?

I was thinking having the text dynamically added and split the words and add them into labels, and having each label click event, but was not sure whether or not a better solution is out there ?

Thank you

Comment: I think we'll need more details here. Is the text entered by the user? Does each word in a text have a different function, or are there, say, 2 words per paragraph that might lead to a function.

Comment: The text will be brought if via a database and split, and will be about 25 words max.  Once a word is tapped, it will action another function that then checks for a match and the word is sounded out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a 'first-cut' - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bBtu6/).

The array represents what you read from a db.

Populate the text area with the array words, putting each word in a span with an appropriately labeled ID.

Click on the span and in this fiddle, the id pops up, but you could do anything you want.

If you could provide more details, perhaps we can refine it further.

What did you mean by "split" the text?

JS

```
var primarytext = ['Lorem','ipsum','dolor','sit','amet','consectetur','adipisicing','elit','sed','do','eiusmod','tempor','incididunt','ut','labore','et','dolore'];

populate();
$('span').on('click', function(){
     $('.putmehere').html(  $(this).attr( 'id' ) );
});

function populate()
{
 for(var n=0; n < primarytext.length; n++)
    {
      $('.mytextdiv').append('<span id=' + n + " '>" + primarytext[n] + ' </span>');
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but I guess using 'span' instead of a 'label' would be faster as its less bulky ?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to handle this, but any inline element would do. You could just leave the text as a single string, but then you'd have to code for where a click occurs in the string, grab the elements before and after spaces, make a new string, etc. Span, to me, just seems the easiest. Once you grab a word, you can then compare it to something, then present it to a sound algorithm that will "sound it out".

Comment: As this is being put into HTML5, could I not use the <audio> tag :  So I can then use as the source `src='https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/' + primarytext[n] +'.mp3'`  within the Span, so the code would just need a `.play()` ?

Comment: I think the <audio> tag would require an audio file like mp3, wav or ogg, not just the text. But if you had the audio equivalent of the word, you could embed the audio file next to the word, then if the word is picked, you just call the file next to it.

Comment: Example <div id='0'><span>Horse</span><audio><source src='horse.mpg' type='audio/mpeg'></source></div> with the div being inline or inline-block

Comment: Here's a little something that will get you started using Google audio files and html5 audio tags.http://jsfiddle.net/TjzH5/  - just click on the word 'horse'.